# How to say "to carry out a study"?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

I'm trying to translate "to carry out a study" like in the following context:

> Two scientists carried out a study on X.

I came up with:

> réaliser une étude sur quelque chose

or

> faire une recherche sur quelque chose.

Would any of those work?

Comment: The original title "carry out a research" is incorrect in English (research is not a count noun). I've modified it to "carry out a study"; we can also say "carry out research" as a mass noun, but in context it sounds like you mean an individual item of research, which is a study.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Whoops, thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that both of your proposals are correct.
In the case of a scientific research you could use `mener` or `mener à bien`.

(https://www.wordreference.com/enfr/carry%20out)

Comment: Pour traduire toute l'expression, je pense que "*mener une étude*" est la meilleure solution.

Answer (score 2):

"Réaliser une étude sur qqch" est tout à fait correct. On peut aussi dire :
"Effectuer une étude sur qqch".

Voir : 
https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/carry+out+a+study.html

Answer (score 1):

In French (I am French), the 2 answers are corrects. But, in the everyday language, we use "faire une recherche...(sur)". Nevertheless, in French, we use the verb "faire" for a lot of expressions. So, if you want more correct French, use "réaliser une étude (sur)..."

Comment: Attention: in French; in English, etc (that is, capital letter) and en français, en anglais and so on.

Comment: Also.  I am French (and not french).

Comment: "Faire une recherche" sounds like “performing a search” for me, i.e. typing something into Google or possibly heading out ot the local library but not engaging in scientific research.